# Tourist or Business visa for France

Tags: visas, schengen, france

I am an international student in the US. I have a job interview invite from an organization in France.  I understand that I need to obtain a short-term visa from the French consulate. I was wondering what classification of visit purpose (tourism or business) I should choose from.

Comment: @henning-makholm Does that mean I need to apply for business visa?

Comment: x @BengaluruSun As the answers to the linked question explain, there is no such thing as a "business visa" in the Schengen area. But when the visa application form asks for the _purpose_ of your visit, "business" is a correct answer. Or you can check "other" and put "job interview" in the write-in field.